# Spreadsheet Compare with locked/hidden cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, comparison

I created a worksheet in Excel 2013 with several tabs. There are a number of values and formulas we do not want users seeing or playing with.  Most of the cells are locked and hidden.  Several of the tabs are hidden and all tabs are protected.  When we open up the worksheet we can see and modify only the areas we want users to have access to.  I used Spreadsheet Compare on two versions of protected worksheets and found that I could see basically everything in the hidden cells and tabs.  Why does Spreadsheet Compare reveal those locked/hidden/protected cells and tabs?  Is there any way to prevent Spreadsheet Compare from showing the values and formulas we do not want others to see?
Thank you.